# Webbrowser.Document.InvokeScript() don't work in IE9

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, webbrowser-control

i trying to call a javascript function with below code

```
Webbrowser.Document.InvokeScript("something")
```

it's work in IE8,but not work in IE9.
Anybody has any suggestion for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with adding following code to `HEAD` tag for `IE 9`

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

Answer (score 0):

try to do emulation like this

```
static private void UseIE9DocMode()
        {
            RegistryKey key = null;
            try
            {
                key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION");
            }
            key.SetValue(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName, 9999, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            key.Close();
        }
```

see those url:
http://deletethis.net/dave/?page=2&q=document
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/03/10/more-ie8-extensibility-improvements.aspx